# MySql : Order differently within the same column

Tags: mysql, random, sql-order-by

I have a table `Foo` with a column '`FooId`'

The users who choose to have the `Foo attribute` set, set it with a `positive integer` while for others the value of this column is `-1`.

Now, I wish to have the contents of the table ordered by the `FooId` column such that the results with positive `FooId` are ordered before the ones that have default value (i.e. -1).
So, I have my query something like `select * from Foo order by FooId desc`.

Now I want to *randomize* my results such that results with `positive 'FooId'` are still before the results with `FooId = -1` but the results are ordered *randomly*. Something with `rand()` should also be okay, as I am not focusing on performance at the moment.

What are my options to formulate the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Foo
ORDER BY IF(FooId>0,RAND(),-0.1) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a `SELECT ... WHERE FooID >=0 ORDER BY RAND()` and then use UNION with another select like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Foo
WHERE FooID >= 0 
ORDER BY RAND() 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
FROM Foo
WHERE FooID == -1;
```

You can concatenate any tables with `UNION ALL` as long as they have the same columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT * FROM Foo ORDER BY if(FooId >= 0, 0, 1), RAND();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below :

```
SELECT * FROM Foo
 ORDER BY IF(FooId > 0,0,1);
```

Comment: I don't think it will randomize. will it?